# Country tag consistency

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've been having a look through the tags, and there's a few country tags from `identify-this-x` questions, however the names aren't very consistent. Some are the name for the nationality, such as:

- [french](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french)
- [spanish](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish)

Whereas some end with the `-movie` suffix, such as:

- [japanese-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-movie)
- [asian-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asian-movie)
- [german-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-movie)

And as I see it, there's 3 different ways this could be dealt with:

- **1.** Rename the [japanese-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-movie), [asian-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asian-movie) and [german-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-movie) to `japanese`, `asian`, and `german` respectively.

  - This is my preferred option as we have no questions about TV shows and we may as well just keep them together with the movies from the same country if they are asked.
  - Typically these tags are used in [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) and [identify-this-tv-show](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show) which indicates whether it's TV or a movie anyway.
- **2.** Rename the [french](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) and [spanish](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish) to `french-movie` and `spanish-movie`.

  - This is safe as there are no questions in those tags about TV shows. If the TV versions are required, they can be created later as `french-tv` and `spanish-tv`.
- **3.** Leave the existing tags as they are, create generic `japanese`, `asian` and `german` tags as well as `french-movie` and `spanish-movie` and have them all aliased to the generic country tags.

Are there any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not going to leap in as I'd prefer someone who's first language is not English to comment first.  It seems to me however that language and/or region are not quite the same thing.  The [tag:spanish] tag has one South American question - perhaps that should be a "Latin-American" or similar tag to match Asian.  Perhaps the question could be expanded to ask "are we addressing language or regions here"

Comment: @iandotkelly That really depends on your interpretation of the tag. For example for French I described it as `Films or television shows created in France or French overseas territories, using the French language or about French characters or historical people.`, so if you interpret it as the Spanish language it fits as it is. This was before I spotted the `-movie` tags of course.

Comment: I think its an excellent thing to discuss and to get an overall opinion.  The site is totally dominated by the English originating media - and it would be nice to have an organized way to find other regions or languages.

Comment: I had an interesting discussion a while back on a question about this, as it was by a Russian director, but made in Sweden with a Swedish cast. It was quintessentially Russian, but I wasn't happy labelling it with any country tag as I felt it simply confused the issue.

Comment: Related: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1036/49.

Answer (score 4):

#### Remove language tags

These serve no real purpose and are primarily used on identification questions. All identification questions should have these tags removed and if any languages are used in a movie that you want identifying, you should mention this in the body of your question

#### Country specific industry tags

While looking through the questions that would remain after removing language tags, it became apparent that just tagging them [film-industry](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film-industry) gives us a group of questions that could result in multiple conflicting questions based on the country of origin of the film industry being discussed. For this purpose it would probably be worth implementing country specific industry tags following the format of [countryname-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countryname-cinema) (for example [french-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-cinema), [american-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-cinema), [iranian-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iranian-cinema) etc).

If we were to go down this route, current tags like [hollywood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollywood) would be removed from identification questions and [hollywood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollywood) would become a synonym of [american-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-cinema).