# Have country tags been deleted?

Tags: support, tags

[Country tag consistency](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/country-tag-consistency) refers to tags about countries, but I can't find country related tags any more. Have they been deleted?

Comment: I vaguely recall the tags being deleted as is proposed by the upvoted answer to that question.  There were not that many, and tags auto delete if they are used on a single question for any amount of time.

Comment: The only tags I remember ever seeing for countries are tags like [tag:american-cinema]... but these tags are only for use discussing the actual cinema of those countries, not generally tagging the country of origin of a specific film... which is meta information and inherent in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [question you link to](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1343/49), which has long been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), has your answer. The result of that discussion was the consensus that language or country tags, **like [french](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) or [japan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan) are to be retired** and transferred into [...-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/...-cinema) tags, like **[indian-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-cinema) or [american-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-cinema), which are to be only used on questions that specifically pertain to the intricacies of those respective movie industries** and *not* on all kinds of questions about an e.g. Indian film nor on ID questions asking for such films.

This policy has since been put to use long ago, resulting in the tags being removed from all questions that they not pertain to anymore and renamed accordingly if they do. And since **tags that don't have any questions are automatically deleted**, they disappeared soon after that. So yes, country tags have been largely deleted from the majority of their questions or renamed into [...-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/...-cinema) tags for questions about the respective movie industry.