# Topic Challenge: Indian Cinema [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [*Baahubali 2: The Conclusion*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4849438/) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2520/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-05-02 00:00 UTC to 2017-05-12 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Indian films (and TV-shows)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add an [indian-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-cinema) tag to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1343/49) instead.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 30 and ~5,244 views) was asked by [*SS.*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/48608), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [How did the word "Bollywood" originate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72568/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Was Chingari ever actually released?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72609/49) (5 / ~57)
3. [Was the Indian animated movie Swami Ayyappan ever released?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/73009/49) (4 / ~36)

   [Who is Bhadra's mother?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72586/49) (4 / ~1,392)

   [Why Anurag's name was not analogous to respective Devdas character?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72708/49) (4 / ~27)

   [Why Kaira preferred disorganizing in her house?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72881/49) (4 / ~11)
4. [How Gaurav's action in the end justified?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72666/49) (3 / ~35)

   [What significance does this poem add to movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72620/49) (3 / ~15)

   [Did they really sell toy guns along with newspaper during K. M. Nanavati trial?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72988/49) (3 / ~26)
5. [Will there be any further movies in Baahubali series or any spin-off?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72996/49) (2 / ~69)
6. [Why is there no cheer from people to Bhallaladeva when compared to Baahubali?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72992/49) (1 / ~38)
7. [How "Rustom Pavri" defend question about "Vikram died with towel" in court?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72983/49) (0 / ~16)